# Evaluating integrals with prior information on parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am working with the Marcenko-Pastur distribution which appears in random matrix theory.

$$\rho(x) = \frac{N Q}{\pi\, \beta\, x}\sqrt{(x_{max}-x)(x-x_{min})},$$ with
$$x_{min}^{max} = \frac{\beta}{2 N} \left(1\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{Q}}\right)^2.$$

I want to calculate some averages with this, say,
$$\int_{x_{min}}^{x_{max}}x \, \rho(x) \,dx.$$

I would like to evaluate this integral in Mathematica symbolically, utilising some information I have on the parameters, such as, $N >> 1$, and $Q \leq 1.$ I am not sure how to do this in Mathematica. I tried integrating without providing any information and it showed some vague results involving imaginary part! I think providing extra information might help.

Comment: It is always a good idea to include the code you have already tried, so we can see what you worked / didn't work, and also we don't have to rewrite your expression from the latex by hand.

Comment: N and Q only multiply the integral. Therefore, your integral is up to a constant multiplier: `Integrate[(xmax-x)(x-xmin),x]` And this results in:` -(x^3/3) - x xmax xmin + 1/2 x^2 (xmax + xmin)`

Comment: @MarcoB You are right. I should have done that. However, for now, my problem seems to be solved. If I need further assistance, I will put the code. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielHuber That's right! I got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use this code to integrate:

```
eval[f_] := Integrate[f/x*Sqrt[(b-x)*(x-a)],{x,a,b},
                      Assumptions->0<a<b];

eval[1]
(* 1/2 (a+b-2 Sqrt[a b]) Pi *)

eval[x]
(* 1/8 (a-b)^2 Pi *)
```

Comment: Likely a typo:  `eval[x]`  performs an error "Integrate::idiv: Integral of Sqrt[-((-4+x) (-1+x))] does not converge on {1,{1,4,0}}."

Comment: I just restarted my kernel and copy-pasted the code here, and get no error on my machine. Maybe it works if you `Clear[x,a,b,f]`?

Comment: @user293787 Thanks! This seems more reasonable approach! And I am not getting error.

Comment: `x`  is the variable of the integration, so `eval[x]` does not seem to be correct.

Comment: Wolfram cloud does not print that. What would be more correct in you opinion? And the correct anwser then.

Comment: As far as I understand it, `f` is a  parameter,  i.e. the one takes numeric values. BTW, `Integrate[f/x*Sqrt[(b - x)*(x - a)], {x, a, b}, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < a < b]` results in `1/2 (a + b - 2 Sqrt[a b]) f \[Pi]` (The integral is expressed in a closed form.).